# Make the Stock Widget display percentage change

Tags: ios, notifications, tweaks

Is there a way to make the Stock Widget in iOS's Notification Center to display percentage change instead of price change? Any Cydia tweak?

In the Stocks.app you can switch between those and market cap by pressing the price change tile on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, the answer is no, you cannot.

The only configuration available for the Stocks Notification Centre widget is Enabled/Disabled.

Other apps that provide Stocks reporting may have been updated to provide more configurable notifications, however the stock (sic) app does not.

Comment: Accepted answer, and INCORRECT.

You can change the way the *widget* displays market change (absolute vs percentage) by going into the Stocks *app* and changing it there. This change then cascades into the widget.

This question was closed with "this question already has an answer" but that answer does NOT make it clear that changing this setting in the Stocks app also changes it in the widget.